# How to draw an inner border?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to draw two border(1 inside - 1 outside) to Column.

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

```
Modifier.border(2.dp) // -> this creates inner border.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```kotlin
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(14.dp)
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.width(58.dp).height(78.dp)
        .clip(shape)
        .border(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Blue, shape = shape)
        .border(width = 4.dp, color = Color.White, shape = shape)
        .background(Color.Blue)
) {}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have different options.

- You can simply apply a `border` modifier and then a `padding`.

Something like:

```
    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(60.dp , 100.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Blue, shape)
        .padding(4.dp)
        .background(Blue, shape)
    ){
      //content
    }
```

[image]

- You can apply the `border` modifier twice:

  ```
    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(60.dp , 100.dp)
        .border(2.dp, Blue, shape)
        .border(4.dp, White, shape)
        .background(Blue, shape)
    ){
        //content
    }
  ```

[image]

- Finally you can draw an *inner* border.

Something like:

```
fun Modifier.innerBorder(
    strokeWidth: Dp,
    color: Color,
    cornerRadiusDp: Dp,
    offset : Offset = Offset.Zero
) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val cornerRadiusPx = density.run { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }
        val halfStroke = strokeWidthPx / 2
        val topLeft = Offset(halfStroke + offset.x, halfStroke + offset.y)

        Modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width -  topLeft.x*2  
            val height = size.height - topLeft.y*2              

            drawRoundRect(
                color = color,
                topLeft = topLeft,
                size = Size(width, height),
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(cornerRadiusPx, cornerRadiusPx).shrink(halfStroke),
                style = Stroke(strokeWidthPx)
            )

        }
    }
)

private fun CornerRadius.shrink(value: Float): CornerRadius = CornerRadius(
    kotlin.math.max(0f, this.x - value),
    kotlin.math.max(0f, this.y - value)
)
```

and then just apply it:

```
   val shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)

   Column(modifier = Modifier
        .size(60.dp , 100.dp)
        .background( Blue , shape)
        .innerBorder(
            strokeWidth = 2.dp,
            color = White,
            cornerRadiusDp = 16.dp,
            offset = Offset(4f,4f)
        )
    ){
      //....content
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your good solution, but the corners of the white part in the result are not exactly what I want. Corners have not equal radius as in my expected result.

Comment: @ssssss I've updated the answer with another solution to draw a real inner border.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
@Composable
fun BorderedBox() {

    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(120.dp)
            .border(3.dp, Blue, shape)
            .padding(4.dp)
            .background(Blue, shape)
    ) {

    }

}
```